# Java- CSV / Delete column in csv file

Tags: java, csv, fileutils

I try to delete a column in csv file in Java.

for example, I have this csv file

```
ID   name1   name2   name3
1    hello   hell    hel
2    try     tr      t
3    browser bro     br
```

and I want the after the next operation: (delete csvFile, 2) it will be:

```
ID   name1   name3
1    hello   hel
2    try     t
3    browser br
```

I found only operations that invlove rows and not column.

Comment: What are you using to handle csv files ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to delete a column in a CSV file is to remove the header and the information of this column in the whole file, that is for each row of the file. Even if you use a third party library it will do this internally.

Comment: which third party libary do this?

Comment: I don't know, but if it is capable of it, it does it as I explain.

Take a look at [JavaCSV](http://sourceforge.net/projects/javacsv/) or [SuperCSV](http://supercsv.sourceforge.net/examples_writing.html)

Answer (score 1):

Read in each column value of each row, and write out only the desired columns while skipping the undesired column value.

## Example app using *Apache Commons CSV* library

Here is an example app demonstrating the use of [*Apache Commons CSV*](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/) to read the input file, then write to the output file, skipping over the unwanted column values.

Notice the use of try-with-resources syntax to automatically close our file reader and writer objects. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html).

[RFC 4180](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180) refers to the written standard defining the [Comma-Separated Values (CSV)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) format.

Make a file named `input.csv`.

```csv
ID,name1,name2,name3
1,hello,hell,hel
2,try,tr,t
3,browser,ro,br
```

Java app.

```java
package work.basil.example;

import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVFormat;
import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVPrinter;
import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVRecord;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.InvalidPathException;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class App
{
    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        System.out.println ( "Hello World!" );
        App app = new App ();
        app.demo ();
    }

    private void demo ( )
    {
        try
        {
            // Read CSV file.
            Path pathInput = Paths.get ( "/Users/basilbourque/input.csv" );
            Path pathOutput = Paths.get ( "/Users/basilbourque/output.csv" );
            try (
                    final BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader ( pathInput , StandardCharsets.UTF_8 ) ;
                    final CSVPrinter printer = CSVFormat.RFC4180.withHeader ( "ID" , "name1" , "name3" ).print ( pathOutput , StandardCharsets.UTF_8 ) ;
            )
            {
                Iterable < CSVRecord > records = CSVFormat.RFC4180.withFirstRecordAsHeader ().parse ( reader );
                // We expect these headers: ID,name1,name2,name3
                for ( CSVRecord record : records )
                {
                    // Read.
                    Integer id = Integer.valueOf ( record.get ( "ID" ) );
                    String name1 = record.get ( "name1" );
                    String name2 = record.get ( "name2" );
                    String name3 = record.get ( "name3" );
                    System.out.println ( "id: " + id + " | name1: " + name1 + " | name2: " + name2 + " | name3: " + name3 );

                    // Write.
                    printer.printRecord ( id , name1 , name3 );
                }
            }
        } catch ( InvalidPathException e )
        {
            e.printStackTrace ();
        } catch ( IOException e )
        {
            e.printStackTrace ();
        }
    }
}
```

Console output.

> id: 1 | name1: hello | name2: hell | name3: hel
>
> id: 2 | name1: try | name2: tr | name3: t
>
> id: 3 | name1: browser | name2: ro | name3: br

Resulting file named `output.csv`.

```csv
ID,name1,name3
1,hello,hel
2,try,t
3,browser,br
```