# how to delete a column from a csv file using java?

Tags: java

[Java- CSV / Delete column in csv file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15084337/java-csv-delete-column-in-csv-file), the answer in this link is not clear can anyone pls suggest me how to do it.

Comment: The top answer for that question is just saying you have to systematically go through each row and delete the cell that corresponds to the column you want removed. Since it's a CSV you can write code to do this, or you could use a library.

Comment: Alberto's comment on the accepted answer has a link to SuperCSV whose javadoc describes [partial writing](http://super-csv.github.io/super-csv/examples_partial_writing.html) whereby you should be able to write all but one column. "As you can see in this example, we're only writing 5 of the available fields from the bean" It seems reasonable that you would read the file, write a new file, remove the old file, rename the new file to the old file's name.

Comment: Use a library such as JavaCSV.  Don't try to write this yourself.  There are too many pitfalls.

Answer (score 4):

Given what a CSV file is, there isn't going to be an easy function call to simply delete a column from the CSV file. To delete a column, you'll need to do a few steps.

1. Open the existing CSV file, `f0`
2. Create a new CSV file `f1`
3. Loop through `f0`. For each line in `f0` write it to `f1`, excluding only the column you don't want.
4. Once you're done reading `f0`, close and delete `f0`.
5. Rename `f1` to `f0`.

Comment: Thanks mate will sure try this.

Comment: @RithinGowda: if this answered your question, please consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) the answer :)